# Change global mouse cursor in .NET

Tags: .net, mouse-cursor

I need ability to modify the cursor while my application is running, and restore it afterwards.

Cursor.Current doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out it's not a good idea to change the cursor globally. Instead I decided to follow the actual cursor via hooks, and draw my object around it.

Answer (score 0):

Well you could try something like this (changing from with a running instance of a form in your application)

```
            this.Cursor = Cursors.Cross;
```

and reset it back to default using

```
            this.Cursor = Cursors.Default;
```

The Cursors class holds various Cursor objects you could use

Comment: That's not what I was looking for. this.Cursor changes only the form cursor, and not the global one.